# Excel: make column based on gain or loss in other column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to generate the second column shown automatically based on if the first column is higher than zero:

[image: example of result I want for second column]

How can I do this with excel?

Comment: you want it unhidden or selective filtered to be visible by computing sum in one cell and check >0 or cell to the left is +

Comment: I want something like this: if(A1>0){this = 1} else {this = 0}

Comment: I added a photo showing the expected result for the second column

Comment: It isn't nearly as complicated as that, this is a simple IF test.  B2 would be: =IF(A2>0,1,0).  In fact, since you want just 1 or 0 corresponding to true or false, you can use just: =A2>0.

Comment: looks like what I want but how do I apply that to every single row rather than a single line? (sorry complete noobie on excel)

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, without @ addressing, comments are like a tree falling in the forest when nobody's there to hear.  I stumbled back across your post.  :-)  If you enter the formula in B2, you can copy it and then paste into the whole range you need.  Or, after entering it in B2, grab the lower right corner of that cell and drag it down as far as you need with your mouse.  The formula will automatically adjust to the local row in each new cell.

Comment: That's exactly right; How did you not search "excel if formula" at some point for this? The first comment you made is exactly what you needed. It doesn't seem like you put much effort into solving this on your own, I'm afraid. Which doesn't make much sense to me considering you have 4k rep on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[All answer assume put into B2 cell and copied down] There are a couple of things to consider. What if the A column cell is blank or has text in it.
+IF(ISNUMBER(A2),{Rest of If }, "") 
the if works as (Test), True value, false value.
The rest of the if we will work on next, the blank just keeps the column empty until there is a value there.

the rest of the if is if (A2>0,1,0) which follows the same format

the overall equation is

- =IF(ISNUMBER(A2),IF(A2>0,1,0),"")